# Why is the apparently malformed yaml the one that validates?

Tags: kubernetes, tabs, yaml, spaces

In the first yaml below, the second `podSelector` clause (under `to`) seems correctly formatted, with two spaces indent for `matchLabels`, consistent with standards and the rest of the yaml.

The second yaml  is identical, but `matchLabels` has four spaces. This format  follows [the  Kubernetes documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) (There are no tabs.)

Yet the first yaml **fails** `kubectl` validation with  *error validating "p.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(NetworkPolicy.spec.egress[0].to[0]): unknown field "matchLabels" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.NetworkPolicyPeer*, and the second **passes** validation.

This does not pass validation:

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
 kind: NetworkPolicy
 metadata:
   name: internal-policy
 spec:
   podSelector:
     matchLabels:
       name: internal
   policyTypes:
   - Egress
   egress:
   - to:
     - podSelector:
       matchLabels:
         name: mysql
```

This passes validation:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: mysql
```

Comment: The second yaml is the one from the docs, and the second yaml is the one which validates? Where is the actual problem then? Why do you use the first yaml at all then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well apparently `matchLabels` should be a key in the mapping value of `podSelector`, hence it must be more indented. This:

```
- podSelector:
  matchLabels:
```

Places `matchLabels` on the same indentation level as `podSelector`, since the initial `-` is treated as part of the indentation as per YAML spec. Basically, there are two indentation levels defined here:

- The level of the sequence, starting with `-`. All subsequent sequence items must have their `-` at the same level.
- The level of the mapping which is a value of the sequence, starting with `p`. All subsequent keys of the mapping must start at the same level.

Therefore, if you want `matchLabels` to be nested in `podSelector`, you must indent it more:

```
- podSelector:
    matchLabels:
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are wrong then. The matchLabels is indeed a child key of a hash under podSelector. Please open an issue on the docs so we can fix it :)

Comment: I would agree that the docs are wrong, because 4 spaces are used in that one place,  but the format in the docs is the format that *passes* validation.