# Property with key [http-client.timers['http-get'].name] not found in properties from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, yaml

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Apache Camel to define and control routing of data. The routes are defined via XML DSL and have property placeholders to allow variability in the defined routes.

I'm getting an error when I try to define and use a collection of items:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with key [http-client.timers['http-get'].name] not found in properties from text: timer:{{http-client.timers['http-get'].name}}?delay={{http-client.timers['http-get'].start-delay}}&fixedRate=true&period={{http-client.timers['http-get'].period}}&repeatCount={{http-client.timers['http-get'].repeat-count}}
```

application.yml:

```
---

camel:
  springboot:
    name: MissionServices
    main-run-controller: true

http-client:
  server:
    host: localhost
    port: 9100
  endpoint: chars?size=500
  timers:
    - http-get:
      name: http-get
      start-delay: 0
      period: 1000
      repeat-count: 5
    - http-post:
      name: http-post
      start-delay: 0
      period: 5000
      repeat-count: 5
```

camel-context.xml:

```
...
  <camelContext id="camel-context"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="http-get">
      <from
        uri="timer:{{http-client.timers['http-get'].name}}?delay={{http-client.timers['http-get'].start-delay}}&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period={{http-client.timers['http-get'].period}}&amp;repeatCount={{http-client.timers['http-get'].repeat-count}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - http-get" />
      <setHeader name="HTTP_METHOD">
        <constant>GET</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <to
        uri="http:{{http-client.server.host}}:{{http-client.server.port}}/{{http-client.endpoint}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - http-get" />
    </route>

    <route id="http-post">
      <from uri="direct:start-http-post" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - http-post" />
      <setHeader name="HTTP_METHOD">
        <constant>POST</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <setHeader name="CONTENT_TYPE">
        <constant>application/json</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <to
        uri="http:{{http-client.server.host}}:{{http-client.server.port}}/{{http-client.endpoint}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - http-post" />
    </route>

  </camelContext>
...
```

Do I have the YAML structured incorrectly, or am I using the wrong syntax in the route definition to access the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all indentation in the yml is not correct.

Secondly the structure isn't quite right. What you are looking for is a Map of Objects with fields name, start-delay, period and repeat-count. But you have declared it as a list.

You are trying to find an object by a key(http-get). You cannot search a list with key. You can search list with index. What you need is a map.

Correct yaml structure should be

```
http-client:
  server:
    host: localhost
    port: 9100
  endpoint: chars?size=500
  timers:
     http-get:
        name: http-get
        start-delay: 0
        period: 1000
        repeat-count: 5
     http-post:
        name: http-post
        start-delay: 0
        period: 5000
        repeat-count: 5
```

To access the value you are looking for should be like this

```
{{http-client.timers.http-get.name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `http-client.timers['http-get'].name` states that `name` is nested in `http-get` while in your YAML:

```yaml
  timers:
    - http-get:
      name: http-get
      start-delay: 0
      period: 1000
      repeat-count: 5
```

`name:` is a sibling of `http-get:` (they share the same indentation level, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041279/347964) for details about indentation handling in that case). Moreover, you start a sequence here (with `-`) but the path does not use any indexing into the sequence. You probably want

```yaml
  timers:
    http-get:
      name: http-get
      start-delay: 0
      period: 1000
      repeat-count: 5
```